# Facebook authentication in asp.net mvc3

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using facebook javascript sdk for authentication & its working but I want to ask how can i make certain parts of my website only accessible if the user is logged in, for eg: if user type: http://www.example.com/Products then he/she must be redirected to login page if he/she is not logged in. How can i do this while using fb javascript sdk?

Answer (score 1):

use FacebookAuthorize attribute

```
[FacebookAuthorize(LoginUrl = "/Account/Login")]
public ActionResult Products() {}
```

look [Getting Started with an ASP.NET MVC 3 Website (With Javascript SDK)](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20with%20an%20ASP.NET%20MVC%203%20Website%20%28With%20Javascript%20SDK%29&referringTitle=Getting%20Started) for more details